# How to attribute different ids to child elements depending on the number of parent-like elements in that container

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, menu

I am developing my Wordpress theme (http://www.dev.visualvisual.com). I have a header menu that will spread its **.menu-items** across the top and a second footer menu that will spread its **.menu-items** across the bottom.

I have positioned each one of these .menu-items elements differently.

The **1st  .menu-item** of the **.header** is on the top left side; when there is a **2nd .menu-item** it will be aligning to the top right side; if there is a **3rd .menu-item**, then the 2nd menu-item will be in the middle; and so on. The more menu-items we have the more they will be "compressed" along the full width of the page. This is working for both .headermenu and .footermenu. 
I have used these css rules to position the **.menu-items**:

```
.headermenu {
    position: fixed;
    top:0vh;
    left:0vw;
    width: 95vw;
    padding-right: 5vw; 
}

.headermenu ul {
    justify-content: space-between; 
    display: flex;
}

.footermenu {
    bottom:0vh;
    left:0vw;
    position: fixed;
    width: 95vw;
    padding-right: 5vw; 
}

.footermenu ul { 
    justify-content: space-between; 
    display: flex;
}
```

So far so good. My problem is that I want to style their children elements depending on the parents position on the page. As I don't know how many menu-items a future user will add (1, 2, 3, 4 or even more "menu-items") I think it's impossible for me to do this just with CSS.

I have wrote this sketchy set of rules to display my **.sub-menu** items:

```
.menu-item > ul.sub-menu {  
    padding: 1vh;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.menu-item:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This set of rules is aligning the .sub-menu items to the center, but if the text is longer than expected, then its parent will naturally increase in width allowing space for its "biggest child".
So now i believe the best option is to:

- always align the children from the first .menu-item on the
  top-left to the left;
- align the children from the last .menu-item on the top-right to
  the right
- in case there are 3 .menu-items, align the children from the last
  .menu-item to the right and the children of the second .menu-item to
  the center.
- in case there are 4 .menu-items, align the children from the last
  .menu-item to the right and the children of the second and third
  .menu-item to the center.
- repeat the logic of point 3) and 4)...

This is my #header structure:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        <div class="headermenu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_1">News</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_a">Alternative Landscapes</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_b">Collection</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_c">Brave</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_d">Abstract Posters</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_e">Pedro, O Mau</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </h1>
</div> <!-- end of header -->
```

This is my footer structure:

```
<div id="footer">
    <h1>  
        <div class="footermenu"> 
            <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_4">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_5">Links</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6">About</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More  Landscapes</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_c">Brave New</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_d">Line Three</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_e">Mary's World</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </h1>
 </div><!-- end of #footer -->
```

I believe the solution must be somewhat related to a javascript loop that checks how many items are in both menus and attributes specific ID in different cases.
My javascript is rudimental but I'm sensing the logic has to be something like:

```
(this is not any type of code)
a) count menu-items
b) if 1 menu-item  > id#left 
c) if 2 menu-items > id#left to menu 1 > id#right to menu 2
d) if 3 menu-items > id#left to menu 1 > id#center to menu 2 > id#right to menu 3
e) if 4 menu-items > id#left to menu 1 > id#center to menu 2 and 3 > id#right to menu 4
f) if 5 menu-items > id#left to menu 1 > id#center to menu 2, 3 & 4 > id#right to menu 5...
```

Would you know how I can at least start phrasing this in Javascript?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do can be achieved using css pseudo elements `:not() :first-child and :last-child`. I have created a sample using your code. Is this what you are looking to do?

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/pEBpRw?editors=1100

Comment: This is great Nasir. However the parents are all aligned to the center in relation to their children max-width. Is there a way to use this CSS strategy and force the parents to align to the same side as their children? Many thanks.

Comment: Yup. Done in the codepen link. Check it again. Have added .menu > .menu-item to all the pseudo elements css in the code so that same alignment is added to parent item. P.S. Please mark the answer if this helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All childrens from .menu-items stay aligned to the center. But first .menu-item child are aligned to the left, and last .menu-item child aligned to the right.

EDIT:

I think now it's better. There was small mistake in previous code and I added few lines. Position of first .menu-item child (ul.sub-menu) is left: 0 and the last child .menu-item child is right: 0.

```css
.headermenu {
    position: fixed;
    top:0vh;
    left:0vh;
    width: 95%;
    padding-right: 5vw; 
}

.headermenu ul {
    justify-content: space-between; 
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.menu > .menu-item {
    position: relative;
}

.headermenu ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}

.headermenu ul .menu-item:first-child ul.sub-menu {
    left: 0;
}

.headermenu ul .menu-item:last-child ul.sub-menu {
    right: 0;
}


.menu-item > ul.sub-menu {  
    padding: 1vh;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.headermenu ul .menu-item:first-child .sub-menu li {
    text-align: left;
}

.headermenu ul .menu-item:last-child .sub-menu li {
    text-align: right;
}

.menu-item:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        <div class="headermenu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_1">News</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_a">Great News!</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_b">News2</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_c">News3</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_d">News4</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_e">Very Last News</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_1">Contact</a>
                 <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_a">AAAAA</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_b">BBB</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_a">Alternative Landscapes</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_b">Collection</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_c">Brave</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_d">Abstract Posters</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_2_e">Pedro, O Mau</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Drazewski. Left menu and central menu are as good as they can get. Unfortunately the last sub-menu is going off the page limits.

Comment: Check again please.  I added few lines.

Comment: Cool. You have solved the alignment but the lines are breaking and the central submenu is aligning to its parent left side. It's looking much closer to the wanted result.

Comment: I think I have solved it almost completely:

There are still some tweaking to do in the central bottom elements, though. I wouldn't have come so far without your help Drazewsky and Nasir. Many thanks. Please let me know if you make it further than this.